# JQVMap - Setting regions as disabled/unselectable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqvmap

I want to set regions in the map without data to be disabled from clicking. Is there any way to do that...I have been successful with disabling color change onRegionOver, but the same regions still responds to click (and changes color of region...). 
I tried calling preventDefault() method from onRegionOver and onRegionClick events...But it did not help...
Would appreciate any help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Late response, but maybe this can help the next person.

```
var states = 'ca,co,tx,ny,ks,mo';        
$('#vmap').vectorMap({
map: 'usa_en',
    selectedRegion: 'tx',
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    color: '#E6E7E9',
    hoverColor: '#03235E',
    enableZoom: false,
    showTooltip: true,
    onRegionOver: function (event, code, region) {
    // if it's not in the approved list, do nothing, 
    // else allow normal behavior
    if (states.toLowerCase().indexOf(code) <= -1) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    },
    onRegionClick: function (event, code, region) {
    // if it's not in the approved list, do nothing, else handle it
    if (states.toLowerCase().indexOf(code) <= -1) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        //handle state click
    }
    }
})
```

Comment: In version 1.5.0 you may need to 
`return false;` instead of `event.preventDefault();` in `onRegionClick`